# javascript in  contentEditor webpart

Tags: web-part

How can we add javascript in CEWP 2010?

Answer (score 4):

CEWP strips some scripts, check this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020573/sharepoint-2010-content-editor-web-part-duplicating-entries/5022765#5022765) that explains how you can still reference a script from an external file, it's not the best practice so you should (if possible) deploy JavaScripts via SharePoint feature.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your .js file to SiteAssets folder of your site with Sharepoint Desighner.
You may apply the file in your CEWP html.

```
​​<script src="/SiteAssets/Scripts/name.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Take into account the time when SP.js is already loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getListItems, “/_LAYOUTS/sp.js”);
</script>
```